# Low power chopper and power inverter

Tags: power-electronics

I'm seeking advice for components I could use in my lab course. My goal is that my students understand experimentally the ideas (circuit as simple as possible) behind a chopper device and a power inverter device without risks (low power) and for a very low cost (I need to buy components for 15 groups of students).

## Chopper:

[image]

Which transistor for S1? I use 1N4001 for S2.

[Maybe I could use a gate for S1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/197654/15609) but I'm stuck to a diode for S2 (but I could buy a diode with a lower voltage drop).

## Power inverter:

[image]

the switches *must* be made by an association of a diode and a transistor (or a gate): what kind of transistor should I choose. Here, I'm also looking for the control circuit (that would ideally be simple too...).

## Specs

- Input/Output voltages < 1V
- Input/Output current < 1A (100mA would be ok)
- Freq < 1kHz

Comment: Why not simplify the first circuit and just use a diode instead of a transistor at S2? (To me, a conventional buck is a better starting point vs. a synchronous one.) I would consider a P-channel MOSFET for S1 as it doesn't require a high-side drive (which can complicate things). For the second, why not use N-channel MOSFETs (which have integrated body diodes) instead of NPN transistors with discrete diodes?

Comment: Also, you need to figure out and specify your intended input voltage and intended output voltage / current if you want specific device recommendations.

Comment: Operating frequency is also required. How are you planning on driving these devices?

Comment: Watch the turn-on time for the 1N4001 diodes. If your switching frequency is high the diodes won't turn on fast enough and you may damage the transistors. You may need a high-speed diode.

Comment: @Andyaka Added specs (hope it sounds reasonable).

Comment: both the input and output voltages are less than 1V? No, they are not reasonable.

Comment: @KyranF ok. So what should I take? Low voltage, low intensity, no risk.

Comment: Why go ! KHz ?!  Coils are more expensive than diodes .use a shottky diode go say 50KHz and benefit with cheap easy to buy small coil.

Comment: I'm not a SMPS guy, but for teaching if you kept the load current small you could us an analog switch for S1. (I think)

Comment: What are you worried about with the voltage? Even UL allows you to go up to 60V without extra protection... 12 or 24V would be pretty well safe for anybody unless you're playing with those sticky EEG pads or something.

Comment: Are these engineering students or toddlers? haha

Comment: @Daniel haha... My lab has power supplies delivering 10V max.

Comment: @Autistic Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Maybe you could turn your comment into an answer, elaborating a bit?

Answer (score 1):

For the top circuit, I suppose you may want to demonstrate the simple relationship \$V_o = V_i\times dutycycle\$.

In that case, using a diode as one of the switch is a bad choice. When the diode is in the on mode, it has a significant voltage drop (comparing to your input of 1V), that means you end up with huge error. At low duty cycle, the current most likely would reverse, and then the diode would go off, causing even more error and additional issue.

If the current is limited to a low value like around 100mA, then one simple way could be to use something cheap and common, like the 2N7000 series N-channel MOSFET or similar for both upper and lower switches. With the input being 1V, you can simply drive both of the gates with 5V logic.

Addition notes in response to comment below:

For example, the relationship mentioned above is the basis for the output stage of a Class-D amplifier (i.e. power electronics), which is employed in some hifi equipment. I searched for Class-D amplifier articles, and here is one relates well to this discussion: [Class D Amplifiers](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3977)

It is probably even more instructive to try it with S2 being a "real" switch (constructed with a MOSFET for example) and then being a diode. At some operating conditions, the two versions may behave similarly. At other operating conditions, the two versions may behave quite differently, for example, at low duty cycle.

By the way, a P-channel MOSFET is most commonly used for the upper switch (as in the article linked above). But with the input (equivalent to Vdd) at 1V, you would need negative gate voltage to turn on a P-MOSFET. That is the reason I suggested a N-MOSFET because an easy to come by 5V CMOS logic output can rise 4V above the 1V Vdd to turn on the N-MOSFET.

Comment: Thanks for your time (+1). Interesting idea: going from power electronics to "pure" electronics. Can I combine your "gate" idea for S1 with a diode for S2 (with a lower drop voltage)?

Comment: With class D amps you have worry about dead-time to prevent shoot-through. I don't quite see this being a good topic for an intro class. (In fact I can see a lot of those MOSFETs popping at the hands of students.)

Comment: I mentioned Class D amp partly in response to cjorssen's comment about power electronics and "pure" electronics. The schematic presented IS the output stage of a Class D amplifier, whether it is used as such or not. Wouldn't it be nice to start with something simple like \$V_o=V_i\times dutycycle\$? That you can check the circuit operation against a simple quantitative description. I originally thought cjorssen might have chosen the circuit because of this attribute. I wonder how easy it is to pop a MOSFET operates under the parameters given. Shoot through is definitely not going to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want your students to blow stuff up then consider any scheme that has cycle by cycle current limit .Example orthodox peak current mode which is well documented elsewhere and chips are easy to find and your students are more likely to come across this in a job .

Comment: Sorry. I'm probably not as fluent in electronics as you are. Could you elaborate a bit more (read I don't understand your answer at all, sorry for my ignorance). Thanks.

Comment: Orthodox current mode is the most common type of current mode.It works by turning the switching device on at a fixed frequency and then turning the device off when a preset current is reached .There are many chips that do this .The LM3842 is cheap and easily available ,It could become the 741 of powerelectronics.

Comment: Ok, thanks (+1). I found [a document](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua143/slua143.pdf) that explain a bit more.